# Jagged JFreeChart line when plotting y=x and showing with Swing

Tags: java, charts, plot, jfreechart

Is there a way to get better quality lines from JFreeChart when it's being used interactively? For example, if I plot y=x with 50 data points [i.e. `(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2) ... (50, 50)`] and show the `ChartPanel` in a `JFrame` I get the following:

[image]

This doesn't happen if I just plot a line with two data points, `(0, 0)` and `(50, 50)`.

These jagged lines are really annoying for analysing data -- I can't easily tell if there really are subtle bumps in it. Is there a way to improve this situation? Other plotting tools such as matplotlib or excel manage to display the line straight.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you right-click and zoom in on both axes? An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would make it easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it for me, and I will make this the default in JFreeChart in the next release:

```
    chart.getRenderingHints().put(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised by that screenshot but would it be possible for you to scale all your data and use custom axis labeling? Just for a try, if you multiply everything by 10, does the jagged effect still appear on the line? If it doesn't, maybe you could scale all your data as a workaround, if you plan to keep using JFreeChart.

Comment: +1 I'm guessing aliasing based on the plot size and zoom factor.